# Swap View with Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two Views (Buttons) Button1 and Button2 at some position on screen and one ImageView now when I click on ImageView Button1 is move on Button2 Position and Button2 is move on Button1 position like below image

[image]

Now when I Click again on ImageView the same process repeat, swap two buttons on its position
I have implement below code but it is not proper

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/notelist"
        layout="@layout/first_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/notelist"
        layout="@layout/second_view" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="BUTTON 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:text="BUTTON 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

first_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Layout01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/switcher" >
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

second_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Layout02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/switcher" >
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please use your image similar to displayed in screenshot

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.flipanimation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView image2;
private boolean isFirstImage = true;
private Button button1, button2;
private float btn1_Xpos, btn2_Xpos, btn1_Ypos, btn2_Ypos;
TranslateAnimation anim, reverseanim;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
    image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

    relativeLayout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (isFirstImage) {

                isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
                btn1_Xpos = button1.getX();
                btn1_Ypos = button1.getY();
                btn2_Xpos = button2.getX();
                btn2_Ypos = button2.getY();

                anim = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
                        btn2_Xpos / 4, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
                        btn2_Ypos / 4);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setDuration(1000);

                reverseanim = new TranslateAnimation(
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, -btn1_Xpos / 4,
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, -btn1_Ypos / 4);
                reverseanim.setFillAfter(true);
                reverseanim.setDuration(1000);

                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                        button2.startAnimation(reverseanim);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                    }
                });
                button1.startAnimation(anim);

            } else {
                isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

                btn1_Xpos = button1.getX();
                btn1_Ypos = button1.getY();
                btn2_Xpos = button2.getX();
                btn2_Ypos = button2.getY();

                anim = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
                        -btn1_Xpos / 4, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
                        -btn1_Ypos / 4);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setDuration(1000);

                reverseanim = new TranslateAnimation(
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, btn2_Xpos / 4,
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, btn2_Ypos / 4);
                reverseanim.setFillAfter(true);
                reverseanim.setDuration(1000);

                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                        button1.startAnimation(reverseanim);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                    }
                });
                button2.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you define what is not *proper* ??

Comment: it always do this : button1 is moving down and button2 is moving up side and also when button1 is move down it just move little bit right side

Comment: you mean you can swap button1 and 2, but if again i want to do the same, it's not working ?

Comment: Use TransitionManager API

Comment: @SweetWisherツ: just copy and paste my code in eclipse you will find what is the issue

Comment: @pskink: any link or demo please

Comment: I don't have xml code ..check [this once](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-1/)

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html

Comment: @SweetWisherツ: I upload the xml please check

Comment: @pskink: please don't waste my time...

Comment: man did you actually read it? this is the working demo: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/new-transitions-framework/ and next time put some more effort in googling...

Comment: more here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/12/12/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-transitions/ and here http://blog.stylingandroid.com/transition-animation-part-1/ the second one shows exactly what you wanna do, again before rude answering do some googling...

Comment: @pskink: dude, you give me developer.android.com link, the whole world know that link and by the way I have googling so much but I can't find proper demo or code for my question thats why I post question here... Lol...

Comment: "you have googling so much..." really? i googled for demos in 5 minutes and gave you three working demos... the last one is exactly what you want to do, man

Comment: @pskink: ya thanks, you have googling a very good and I will use that link in future , but recently that are not helpful for me for my issue

Comment: @pskink: If you can give solution then post your code as answer of my question

Comment: aha ok, good luck then, and again the solution is reading the last link i gave you: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/transition-animation-part-1/, see the first demo video...

Comment: @pskink: ok , Let me try using that code

Comment: here you have the working code snippet: http://pastebin.com/n1viXjd2

Comment: @pskink: TransitionManager is only supported in kitkat version API Level 19 only....

Comment: so use the backport library

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=TransitionManager+backport&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr

Comment: backport library means ?

Comment: it means that you can use it the same way you are using google's support libraries: it backports some features from some API version to earlier API, the same way using support-v4 you can use Fragments in pre v4 SDK

Comment: There is no any backport library or alternative available for TransitionManager support on lower version of android

Comment: did you google for "TransitionManager backport" ??? this is the result: https://www.google.com/search?q=TransitionManager+backport&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr,ssl, the **FIRST** link is: https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport (guerwan/TransitionsBackport · GitHub), you really should change your attitude, otherwise you will not be able in the future to find the people who will do your homework...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66652/discussion-between-jayesh-and-pskink).